# positioning a dynamically added video

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a code to add a video to the page using pure javascript:

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
var source = document.createElement('source');

 source.src = src;
 source.type = type;

element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');
video.setAttribute("id", "video-style"); // I don't know if this line sets the id or not?!

document.body.appendChild(video);

addSourceToVideo(video, 'vids/gf.mp4', 'video/mp4');

video.play();
```

How can I select and position the video to the center using CSS?

I have tried to select the video with no success:

```
#video-style{
//code to center
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make the video element in center? Then you should wrap your video element with div element.

Comment: You can use your browser's dev tools DOM/page inspector to see if the ID is there. If not, try adding it after video is appended to the DOM. You might need to get a reference to your newly appended element before you can setAttribute on it

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested, but should get the job done.  Flexbox...I put that shhh on everything. This should center the video horizontally and vertically.

Generally when aligning things in CSS is that it's easier to target a parent container.

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
var source = document.createElement('source');

 source.src = src;
 source.type = type;

element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');
video.setAttribute("id", "video-style"); // I don't know if this line sets the id or not?!

document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(video);

addSourceToVideo(video, 'vids/gf.mp4', 'video/mp4');

video.play();
```

```
#video-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```
<div id="video-container">

</div>
```